# Symfony 1.4: How do I get caching working with ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, caching, symfony1

I have some actions that are meant to be used in ajax requests.

If I view the page in the browser, the response is cached as it should be.  However, in ajax requests it's not.

The request method is GET and without GET params.

sfViewCacheManager doesn't even call isXMLHttpRequest() so it's quite confusing why this isn't working...

Is there a setting somewhere for enabling cached ajax requests?

Comment: How do you know the ajax response is not cached? Are you sure the request is called with a GET method?

Comment: And are you absolutely sure it's without GET params? Some JS libraries will helpfully add a cache-busting parameter on for you, even if you don't specify parameters to them. Can we see your code, please? Also, what does, e.g. Firebug, tell you about the request and response headers?

Comment: In the cache configuration for your action try to change with_layout directive to false. I'm not sure, but how the ajax response don't have layout it may be a problem.
look this: http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/21#chapter_21_action_cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% ideal but I've come up with a solution to this.  It seems that caching only works by default when you use a template.  I was responding via `return $this->responseText($json);`.

Responding via a minimal PHP template got the caching running.

```
#jsonSuccess.php
<?php echo $json ?>
```

Would still be good to know if there's a way of making responseText trigger the caching mechanism as it would be slightly faster than running through a template.

Funny enough, the caching now even works while use GET query params.  I think this may have been something they enabled in Symfony 1.3/1.4.

In order to tell what was being cached, I added a 'created_at' header to the response when viewing in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

The following did the trick for me when caching jQuery autocomplete responses:

- Remove the additional timestamp parameter from the jQuery script

  replace:

  ```
  var extraParams = {
    timestamp: +new Date()
  };
  ```

  by:

  ```
  var extraParams = {};
  ```
- Enable cache in cache.yml, with layout. Without the layout it did not seem to work:

  ```
  loginFacility:
    enabled:     true
    with_layout: true
    lifetime:    86400
  ```
- Remove the Pragma header in the action, as this was automatically set to 'no-cache':

  ```
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader("Pragma", "");
  ```

My action now looks like this:

```
public function executeLoginFacility(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->getResponse()->setContentType('application/json');
  $this->getResponse()->setHttpHeader("Pragma", "");
  $facilities =  Doctrine_Core::getTable('Facility')->findLoginFacilitiesForAutocomplete(
        $request->getParameter('q'),
        $limit);

  return $this->renderText(json_encode($facilities));
}
```

Now, when doing a lot of auto-completes, the responses are cached by Symfony and firefox is retrieving them from its own cache. At least that what it looks like in Firebug.

I found that adding a template to the mix instead of returning strait from the action only resulted in a larger cached file in the Symfony cache. I could not see a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony always disable Cache when `POST` or `GET` or other HTTP Headers are sent with a page.

So your AJAX query is not cached because you are sending `GET` parameters to page you want to be cached.

The best way to test that is : add `GET` params and view page "in browser" as you said, and you ll see that Cache will not work.

So disable `POST` and `GET` or other Header PUT DEL from Ajax call and cache will work fine.

To disable `Get`/`Post` : http://www.panteo.net/article/en/1/developpement-symfony-php/cache-symfony-and-appels-ajax.html